# Problem with the joining of SQL tables via relationships

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am currently having problems trying the run a query for some tables.

Below is what I am trying to do, I just can't seem to get it to work.
I have also duplicated constituent and gifts to show you the relations between soft credit and gifts/constituents

[Link to Table Relations Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ap2uH.jpg)

```
SELECT 
    Constituent.lookup_id,
    Constituent.name,
    SplitGifts.amount,
    SplitGifts.giftaidamount
FROM 
    dbo.Gifts Gifts
INNER JOIN dbo.Constituent Constituent
    ON Constituent.id = Gifts.constituent_id
INNER JOIN dbo.SplitGifts SplitGifts
    ON SplitGifts.giftid = Gifts.id
LEFT JOIN dbo.SoftCredit SoftCredit
    ON SoftCredit.giftid = Gifts.id
INNER JOIN dbo.Constituent Constituent_1
    ON Constituent_1.id = SoftCredit.constituentid
INNER JOIN dbo.Gifts Gifts_1
    ON Gifts_1.id = SoftCredit.giftid
INNER JOIN dbo.Package Package
    ON Package.id = SplitGifts.packageid
WHERE 
    Package.lookup_id = N'CORPCHAL'
```

Basically, I want the 
amount and gift_aid_amount from [SplitGifts]
Constituent Name & lookup_id from [constituent] to show up for all Gifts however if a soft credit exists for that gift I need it to get the same fields via the [SoftCredit] table -> Gifts -> SplitGifts -> Fields

Comment: All those parentheses make the query hard to read. Skip them and instead make sure to write the joins in the right order.

Comment: Hi, Sorry about that, I did include a link to the image to try and explain it better.

Comment: Can you  try the query I just edited.

Comment: I don't found the Package reference in your joining where as you use it in the WHERE clause as - where ("Package"."lookup_id" = N'CORPCHAL')

Comment: I have updated the post and included a new image with the package lookup_id

Comment: @PratikBhavsar That only shows the fields from soft credits only.

Comment: And what if there are multiple SoftCredit records referring to a single Gifts record? And what if the Gift record referred to by a SoftCredit record has in turn other SoftCredit records referring to it? (Can become quite complex, right?)

Comment: According to you selection and filter, is that really required to add last 4 tables?

Comment: @BartHofland - Exactly it. What I might have to do is show two separate grids, one showing the gifts minus any linked to soft credits and another grid showing soft credits.

Comment: @mkRabbani No, they are not needed, I was showing the route to take if a soft credit exists.

Comment: OK. But that does not solve possible circular/hierarchical references. Technically, a Gift can be referred to from a SoftCredit. That SoftCredit provides another (alternative) Gift. But that other (alternative) gift can also be referred to from another SoftCredit, providing other (alternative) gifts on their turn. And so on and so on...

Comment: @BartHofland yes, so if say a gift of £100 has 3 soft credits referencing it. I would expect each constituent linked to them soft credits to have £100 on each of their lines. It does get a bit complicated when looking at it. I will keep trying and hopefully crack it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try if the query below works.

```
SELECT 
    Constituent.lookup_id,
    Constituent.name,
    SplitGifts.amount,
    SplitGifts.giftaidamount
FROM 
    dbo.Gifts Gifts
    LEFT JOIN dbo.SoftCredit SoftCredit ON SoftCredit.giftid = Gifts.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Gifts Gifts_1 ON
        Gifts_1.id = SoftCredit.giftid OR
        (SoftCredit.giftid IS NULL AND Gifts_1.id = Gifts.id)
    INNER JOIN dbo.Constituent Constituent ON
        Constituent.id = SoftCredit.constituentid OR
        (SoftCredit.constituentid IS NULL AND Constituent.id = Gifts_1.constituent_id)
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitGifts SplitGifts ON SplitGifts.giftid = Gifts_1.id
    INNER JOIN dbo.Package Package ON Package.id = SplitGifts.packageid
WHERE 
    Package.lookup_id = N'CORPCHAL'
```

It joins back to table `Gifts` (using alias `Gifts_1`) on the gift reference in `SoftCredit` or to itself if there is no `SoftCredit`.

Table `Constituent` is joined in a similar fashion: it joins on the value of `SoftCredit.constituentid` and when NULL, it falls back to `Gifts_1.constituent_id`.

All next joins regarding the gift should refer to `Gifts_1` then.

I have not tested it though. But it might give you a hint in a possible solution direction.

Comment: The gifts with soft credits attached are showing the original constituent name rather than the soft credits constituent name on that query. Thanks for this though

Comment: Ah. Perhaps the same strategy can be used for joining the `Constituent` table in that case. I will update my answer.

Comment: Updated. I was not sure if the `SoftCredit.constituentid` field is nullable. If it would be NULL, it will also fall back to the gift's constituent.